# Display Image in Blank App (Universal Windows - C++/CX)

Tags: c++, image, uwp, c++-cx

Project Type:

[image]

My Code:

```
Image^ img = ref new Image();
img->Width = piece;
img->Height = piece;
Canvas::SetLeft(img, x * field + field / 2 - piece / 2);
Canvas::SetTop(img, y * field + field / 2 - piece / 2);
img->Source = ref new BitmapImage(ref new Uri("E:\\C++\\Assets\\Ball.png"));
csmain->Children->Append(img);
```

It won't display the Image stored at the path. The Image is not even visible. I have no clue.
I'm new to C++ but I know C# very well.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: its not code. its just an image of what i selected in "create new project"

Answer (score 0):

> It won't display the Image stored at the path. The Image is not even visible.

You can't display the image with path directly in UWP platform. (`img->Source = ref new BitmapImage(ref new Uri("E:\\C++\\\\Assets\\Ball.png"));`) If you do want to display image file from above path, please use filepicker to open it, and convert it to [`BitmapImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source?view=winrt-19041#using-a-stream-source-to-show-images-from-the-pictures-library), or access this file with windows storage api. The premise is that you need to enable `broadFileSystemAccess` capability. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).